# Call to undefined function odbc_prepare()

Tags: xampp

i want use odbc in xampp php 7.2. odbc_connect work fine, odbc_exec insert data.

I try insert data using odbc_prepare and odbc_execute. Bud server write: "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function  odbc_prepare() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sql.php:40 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sql.php on line 40"

Code:

```
$connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=dec-sql07;DATABASE=kniha_operatoru"; 

$user = "appoper"; 
$pass = "Kniha_Operatoru"; 

$conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass); 

var_dump($conn);

$query = "INSERT INTO uzivatel (login,heslo) VALUES (?,?)";

$stmt    = odbc_prepare($conn,$query);
$success = odbc_execute($stmt,array('ATomas','heslo'));

var_dump($success);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have odbc extension enabled?

Comment: yes i have enabled extension odbc